# Uploading Image Location to DB and Image File to Directory using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, image-uploading

could I get some assistance with this example code please, trying to add an image to the file directory while storing the link location in the database, but using PDO instead of the old way.

It is based on an example I found online which comes with a dbconnect.php, save.php, addstudent.php and some others not needed for this query.

```
    <form method="post" name="frmStudent" action="save.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $ppid; ?>"/>
        <table>
            <tr><td>First Name</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" required="required" value="<?php echo $pfname; ?>"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Last Name</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="lname" required="required" value="<?php echo $plname; ?>"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Contact No.</td><td>:</td><td><input type="tel" name="contact" required="required" value="<?php echo $pcontact; ?>"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email</td><td>:</td><td><input type="email" name="email" required="required" value="<?php echo $pemail; ?>"/></td></tr>
             <tr><td>Image</td><td>:</td><td><input type="file" name="email" required="required" value="<?php echo $pimg_url; ?>"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td><input type="submit" class="myButton" value="Save"/></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

This is the code that saves to the database

```
<?php   
error_reporting(0);
    include ("dbconnection.php");
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $contact=$_POST['contact'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $img_url=$_POST['img_url'];
    $id=$_POST['pid'];
    if($id==null){
            $sql="INSERT INTO student(fname,lname,contact,email,img_url)values(:fname,:lname,:contact,:email,:img_url)";
            $qry=$db->prepare($sql);
            $qry->execute(array(':fname'=>$fname,':lname'=>$lname,':contact'=>$contact,':email'=>$email,':img_url'=>$img_url));
    }else{
            $sql="UPDATE student SET fname=?, lname=?, contact=?, email=?, img_url=? where id=?";
            $qry=$db->prepare($sql);
            $qry->execute(array($fname,$lname,$contact,$email,$img_url,$id));   
    }
    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Saved!')</script>";
    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
?>
```

Any insights on how to do this would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You need to clean up your code via basic abstractions

Comment: And yeah, it will easy to break your system with that bunch of code

Comment: Too much information you reckon?

Comment: No, it's not that much, but the code is full of bad practices, including : 1) Opened to SQL injection 2) `open_base_dir` problem because of relative patches 3) Missing abstractions

Comment: Apologies, I get that your well versed in this area, however before I can address points 1, 2, and 3 can you perhaps highlight them somehow? My learning style is more visual then textual.

Comment: In-fact i think it best if simplify the question by removing the code that is no longer of use. And simply ask how to do I add an image to the the file directory and location the DB using PDO.

Comment: You need to give more detail than just saying that it "stopped working". In what way is it not working? Are you getting errors? Is your file not uploading? Are records not being inserted into your database?

Comment: Hi Patrick, a recent upgrade to MySQL 5.6 basically knocked out the use of some old vulnerable code I was using so I am learning to migrate things using PDO, howvever in this particular example I am would like to know how to upload an image with the code provided above.

Comment: Right, but you haven't said what's not working with your PDO code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all start by fixing the `HTML` input for the image

```
<tr>
    <td>Image</td><td>:</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="image" required="required" value=""/></td>
</tr>
```

then expand on your `PHP` code:

```
<?php   
error_reporting(0);
include ("dbconnection.php");

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){ 
    $folder = "upload/"; 
    $file = basename( $_FILES['image']['name']); 
    $full_path = $folder.$file; 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $full_path)) { 
        echo "succesful upload, we have an image!";
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        $lname=$_POST['lname'];
        $contact=$_POST['contact'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $img_url= $full_path;
        $id=$_POST['pid'];
        if($id==null){
            $sql="INSERT INTO student(fname,lname,contact,email,img_url)values(:fname,:lname,:contact,:email,:img_url)";
            $qry=$db->prepare($sql);
            $success = $qry->execute(array(':fname'=>$fname,':lname'=>$lname,':contact'=>$contact,':email'=>$email,':img_url'=>$full_path));
        }else{
            $sql="UPDATE student SET fname=?, lname=?, contact=?, email=?, img_url=? where id=?";
            $qry=$db->prepare($sql);
            $success = $qry->execute(array($fname,$lname,$contact,$email,$full_path,$id));   
        }

        if($success){
            echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Saved!')</script>";
            echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
        }else{
            echo 'db transaction failed';
        }
    } else { 
       echo "upload received! but process failed";
    } 
}else{ 
    echo "upload failure ! Nothing was uploaded";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks verymuch Meda, a step in the right direction, however as always there is something else. LOL!
I the file uploads, i get "succesful upload, we have an image!" but I also get "db transaction failed", funny thing is, it does save to the DB creating a new record. But when I try to update that same record it does not update the image fields contents instead it creates another new record. Going to adjust a few things to see If I can get the desired effect. Thanks again and if you have anymore tips/code that would be great!

Comment: @kodenavi what do you mean

Comment: huh?ok let me simplify the issue better.
- the file upload works and places image file in the directory
- upon submitting form i get "successful upload, we have an image!" and with "db transaction failed"
- This is incorrect because it does complete the DB Transaction
- However I use the same form to based on the ID update the form case I want to update that same record, but instead of updating it creates new record.

Comment: @kodenavi is pid null? as for the db error you can remove this check if you want

Comment: on updating a record.. pid is not null as it need to update that very same record. But make sense to look deeper in that area as to why its not updating that record and making a new one.

Comment: @kodenavi `if($id==null)` is evaluating to true I suggest you to `var_dump($_POST)` and check the values there

Comment: Thanks for that didnt help but I changed ':pimg_url'=>$pimg_url to ':pimg_url'=>$full_path instead this seem to resolve by new and updating record issues.

Comment: @kodenavi sorry about that, I forgot to replace that variable, glad you figured out, you can close this question by accepting the answer if you feel like it :)

Comment: Hi, well after pulling my hair out a few times, it seems I have more issues. This current code is very dependant on the file upload, if i dont upload a file I cant add or update the record. How do I make the upload optional?

Comment: @kodenavi Would you like me to update my answer to fix this issue? but please accept it when it does solve it?

Comment: Hi Meda, I will mark this as answered as you have helped me loads! I have finally figured out the problem, had to edit alot but you have given the head start i needed thanks!

Comment: @kodenavi please post new answer with full working code, so that it will be helpfull for others.....

Answer (score 5):

To people who can't get Meda's answer to work, just add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `<form>` element.